# Impedimento al vincular una consulta dentro de otra mediante Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

Cordial saludo agradezco por favor su ayuda con el siguiente inconveniente
tengo los siguiente para realizar la resta entre dos consultas en una misma tabla:

```sql
SELECT * FROM
(select DENSE_RANK() OVER(order by Oro desc, Plata desc, Bronce desc) AS idposicion,
    Pais, 
    Oro, 
    Plata, 
    Bronce, 
    Oro + Plata + Bronce AS Total 
   FROM olimpicos1)  C1 
full outer JOIN
(
  select Pais, ((select Max(Oro) from olimpicos1)-Oro) as Diferencia_con_el_Maximo_de_oros 
  from olimpicos1
) C2 
ON C1. Pais=C2. Pais 
ORDER BY idposicion asc,C1. Pais,C2 .Pais;
```

a esto le llamo (Consulta 1)

Al ejecutar la anterior consulta me muestra de manera adecuada lo que necesito aunque en la consulta que va despues
del full outer JOIN Sobra el campo Pais (si quito dicho campo Pais no me muestra la consulta), pero en fin  lo importante es que me muestra lo que necesito.

tengo otra consulta para adjuntar, pero esta no me funciona si le incluyo el campo Pais, pero si me muestra la resta que necesito, la consulta es:

```sql
select V1.Maximo- V2.Puntaje as Resta FROM
(
  select Max(Oro + Plata + Bronce) as Maximo FROM olimpicos1
) As V1, 
(
  select(Oro + Plata + Bronce) as Puntaje FROM olimpicos1
) as V2;
```

a esto le llamo (Consulta 2)

El poblema de fondo es que necesito incluir esta ultima  consulta (Consulta 2) debajo de la (Consulta 1):

```sql
SELECT * FROM
(select DENSE_RANK() OVER(order by Oro desc , Plata desc, Bronce desc) AS idposicion,
    Pais, 
    Oro, 
    Plata, 
    Bronce, 
    Oro + Plata + Bronce AS Total 
   FROM olimpicos1)  C1 
full outer JOIN
(
  select Pais, ((select Max(Oro) from olimpicos1)-Oro) as Diferencia_con_el_Maximo_de_oros from olimpicos1
) C2 
full outer JOIN
(
  select V1.Maximo- V2.Puntaje as Resta FROM
  (
    select Max(Oro + Plata + Bronce) as Maximo FROM olimpicos1
  ) As V1, 
  (
    select (Oro + Plata + Bronce) as Puntaje FROM olimpicos1
  ) as V2
)C3
ON C1. Pais=C2. Pais AND C2.Pais=C3.Pais 
ORDER BY idposicion asc,C1. Pais,C2 .Pais,C3 .Pais;             --(Linea donde muestra el error)
```

Pero me muestra el siguiente error en la última linea:

> Mens. 512, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 364
> La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza como expresión.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!.

Comment: Sufres del [Problema XY](https://es.accentsconagua.com/articles/code/what-is-the-xy-problem-and-why-is-it-bad.html). Lo mejor sería que indicaras lo que estás tratando de obtener para poder dar una solución más eficiente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplifiqué un poco tu query, creo que esta es la query que estás buscando, si falta alguna columna calculada me avisas y la reviso.

Utilizo una subquery `maximos` para obtener la cantidad de oros que tiene el país con mayor cantidad de oros, y la cantidad de medallas (Oro + Plata + Bronce) que tiene el país con mayor cantidad de medallas. Luego hago un `CROSS JOIN` entre la tabla olimpicos1 y la subquery `maximos` (devuelve el producto cartesiano).

```
SELECT 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Oro DESC , Plata DESC, Bronce DESC) AS idposicion,
    Pais, 
    Oro, 
    Plata, 
    Bronce, 
    Oro + Plata + Bronce AS Total,
    maximo_de_oros - Oro AS Diferencia_con_el_Maximo_de_oros,
    maximo_puntaje - (Oro + Plata + Bronce) AS Diferencia_con_el_Maximo_Puntaje

FROM olimpicos1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT  
                  Max(Oro) AS maximo_de_oros,  
                  Max(Oro + Plata + Bronce) as maximo_puntaje
            FROM olimpicos1) AS maximos

ORDER BY idposicion;
```

Salida (con datos de ejemplo):

| idposicion | Pais | Oro | Plata | Bronce | Total | Diferencia_con_el_Maximo_de_oros | Diferencia_con_el_Maximo_Puntaje |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Argentina | 10 | 1 | 1 | 12 | 0 | 9 |
| 2 | Brasil | 2 | 2 | 2 | 6 | 8 | 15 |
| 3 | Perú | 1 | 10 | 10 | 21 | 9 | 0 |

Algunos problemas con tu query:

- En el primer `FULL OUTER JOIN` te falta el `ON` y las columnas que utilizas para vincular.
- En el segundo `FULL OUTER JOIN` utilizas para vincular la columna `C3.Pais`, pero esta no existe en la subquery `C3`; y esta parte `C1.Pais = C2.Pais` debería ir en el ON del primer `FULL OUTER JOIN` (y quitar el `AND`).
- Utilizas la columnas `C3.Pais` para ordenar, pero no existe. Deberías agregar la columna `Pais` en la subquery `V2` y luego en la subuqery `C3`; así la podrías utilizar para vincular en el segundo `FULL OUTER JOIN` y también al ordenar.

Arreglando esos detalles deja de fallar, y aparentemente el resultado es el deseado, aunque utilizas demasiadas subqueries.

Comment: nachuspiu, infinidad de gracias completamente es lo que necesitaba, un cordial abrazo desde Bogotá.

Comment: De nada @MartínHernández!!!! Me alegra que mi query te haya sido util. Abrazo desde Argentina!